# How can I implement the momentum variant of stochastic gradient descent in sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have read the documentation and various sources online but I am not sure how to implement the momentum variant of SGD in sklearn for a linear regression model. Any help to get me started would be appreciated.

```py
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
X,y = load_boston().data,load_boston().target
clf = linear_model.SGDRegressor(loss='squared_loss',penalty='l2',alpha=0.01,max_iter=1000)
clf.fit(X, y)
print('Score:',clf.score(X,y))
print('Regression coefficients:',clf.coef_)
print('deviation:',clf.intercept_ )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One work-around is to use a `MLPRegressor` without hidden layer which is the same thing as performing a `LinearRegression`.

This will allows you to use momentum variation of `SGD` such as `adam`.

You can do as follows:

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor

from sklearn.datasets import make_regression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X, y = make_regression(n_samples=5_000, random_state=1, n_features=10)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)

clf = MLPRegressor(solver='adam',
                    alpha=0.01,
                    max_iter=5000,
                    hidden_layer_sizes=(),
                   )


clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
print('Score:',clf.score(X_test,y_test))
print('Regression coefficients:',clf.coefs_[0])
print('deviation:',clf.intercepts_ [0])
```

Comment: thank you so much! That is such a good answer! In addition, regarding the parameter "momentum", which according to the documentation for MLPRegressor is between 0 to 1 and is 0.9 for default. Do you know what that 0 - 1 value actually represents?

Comment: You can see momentum as a kind of moving average of the previous gradients. with a momentum=0.9, you are considering for the next sgd step the past 10 updates. With 0, you have no mementum meaning that the update is simply the derivatives of the parameter.